# check if class exists on that page javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an index page and a dashboard, on the index I'm using typewriter and particlesjs on the index only, and on the dashboard I have a sidebar.

If I have all the code as-is, I get errors as the page is still looking for typewriter and particlesjs on all pages.

So I have attempted to wrap each section around an `if` so the plan is if that class or id exists on that page it will only render that JS. So I've created the following code.

edited code below based on `groovy_guy`'s answer

```js
document.querySelector('nav .toggle').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.querySelector('nav .hidden').classList.toggle('show')
});

let checkTypewriter = document.getElementById('typewriter');
if (checkTypewriter.length > 0) {
  new Typewriter('#typewriter', {
    strings: ['Website Developer', 'Freelancer' , 'System Admin'],
    autoStart: true,
    loop: true
  });
}

let checkParticlesjs = document.getElementsByClassName('particlesjs');
if (checkParticlesjs.length > 0) {
  let particles = Particles.init({
    selector: '.particlesjs',
    color: ['#48F2E3', '#48F2E3', '#48F2E3'],
    connectParticles: true,
    maxParticles: 200
  });
}

let checkSidebar = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar');
if (checkSidebar.length > 0) {
  user_wants_collapse = false;

  // Fetch all the details element.
  const details = document.querySelectorAll("details");

  // Add the onclick listeners.
  details.forEach((targetDetail) => {
    targetDetail.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // Close all the details that are not targetDetail.
      details.forEach((detail) => {
        if (detail !== targetDetail) {
          detail.removeAttribute("open");
        };
      });
    });
  });

  document.querySelector('section').addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    // close any open details elements that this click is outside of
    let target = ev.target;
    let detailsClickedWithin = null;

    while (target && target.tagName != 'DETAILS') {
      target = target.parentNode;
    };

    if (target && target.tagName == 'DETAILS') {
      detailsClickedWithin = target;
    };

    Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('details')).filter(
      (details) => details.open && details != detailsClickedWithin
    ).forEach(details => details.open = false);

    // if the sidebar collapse is true and is re-expanded by clicking a menu item then clicking on the body should re-close it
    if (user_wants_collapse == true && (document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar details'))) {
      document.querySelector('body').classList.add('is--expand');
    };
  });

  // when the sidebar menu is clicked this sets the user_wants_collapse var to true or false and toggles is--expand class on body
  document.querySelector('.sidebar .menu-link').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('is--expand');
    user_wants_collapse = !user_wants_collapse

    document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.toggle('is--expand');

    // show all text
    document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar .title').forEach((el) => {
      el.classList.toggle('hidden');
    });

    // changing sidebar menu items and menu collapse icons
    const icon = document.querySelector('.menu-link-arrows span');

    if (icon.classList.contains('fa-angle-double-left')) {
      icon.classList.remove('fa-angle-double-left');
      icon.classList.add('fa-angle-double-right');
    } else {
      icon.classList.remove('fa-angle-double-right');
      icon.classList.add('fa-angle-double-left');
    }
  });

  // making sure the sidebar menu items re-expands the sidebar on click
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar details');
  let i;

  for (i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      // changing sidebar menu items and menu collapse icons
      // change menu items and menu collapse icons
      const icon = document.querySelector('.sidebar-drop-parent-arrow span');

      if (icon.classList.contains('fa-chevron-down')) {
        icon.classList.remove('fa-chevron-down');
        icon.classList.add('fa-chevron-up');
      } else {
        icon.classList.remove('fa-chevron-up');
        icon.classList.add('fa-chevron-down');
      }

      if (document.querySelector('body').classList.contains('is--expand')) {
        document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('is--expand');
      };
    });
  };
};
```

when loading the JS I'm not getting any console errors but I'm not seeing any result of the JS.

Comment: Could https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName not be of any help? Then you can just do a check if the result is null / undefined?

Comment: @ConnorTJ I've added come code changes, however, still getting the same result

Comment: `document.getElementById('typewriter')[0]` is useless. There can only be one element with that id as it must be unique per-document, and even if there were more than one (which would have to be fixed first), `getElementById` will always only retrieve the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `querySelector()`? I think that's more uniform across your codebase. Besides, I see that you only care about one element and not a list of elements, so this method is ideal since it gets the first element that encounters.

```js
const checkTypewriter = document.querySelector('#typewriter')
if (checkTypewriter) {
  // Element with an ID 'typewriter' exist in the DOM.
}

const checkParticlesjs = document.querySelector('.particlesjs')
if (checkParticlesjs) {
  // Element with a class named "particlesjs" exist in the DOM.
}
```

Also, make sure to check if an element exist before attaching an event listener:

```js
const toggleNav = document.querySelector('nav .toggle')

if (toggleNav) {
  toggleNav.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('nav .hidden').classList.toggle('show')
  });
}
```

Comment: You can do `toggleNav?.addEventListener` in 2021.

Comment: You're right @connexo. We can use the optional chaining operator nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

**For Javascript:**

```
var checkTypewriter = document.getElementsByClassName('typewriter');
    if (checkTypewriter.length > 0) {
        // Here write your code
    }

var checkParticlesjs = document.getElementsByClassName('particlesjs');
    if (checkParticlesjs.length > 0) {
        // Here write your specific code
    }
```

**For JQuery:**

```
    if ($("#typewriter")[0]){
        // Here write your code
    } 

    if ($(".particlesjs")[0]){
        // Here write your specific code
    }
```

This is how you can check if your classes exist,

Comment: Not using jQuery

Comment: @debugabug updated the answer for Javascript as well

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')` when going to the dashboard on the typewriter

Comment: There is no `getElementsById`. An id can only occur once in a document, that's why it's `getElementById`.

Comment: I noticed that I changed it too `getElementById` still getting the same error @connexo

Comment: @debugabug try using the `Class Name` instead of `Id` for your typewriter element

Comment: Yeah changing it to a class works @groovy_guy

Comment: glad to know it worked for you :)